# Edit options while using remote server

Tags: python, emacs, remote-server

I usually work in remote server.
I am currently using emacs for editing. while I open particular file, for example, "test.py", I can't get automatic indentation, color profiles for index, python keywords, functions etc. Is there any solution for that??
Moreover I love to use TextWrangler but I can't open file in this editer from my remote host. Is there  away to open and edit files from TextWrangler??

Comment: I used to work on a remote server and I just worked locally (using notepad ++) then uploaded my file whenever I was done with my edits.  It was a little bothersome, but you could always just write a script that auto-uploads and runs whatever script you want. Unfortunately I know nothing about emacs, so I can't really help with that

Comment: I use vim on some remote servers, and the settings are loaded from ~/.vimrc. If you ssh into the remote server, then I believe you're using the ~/.vimrc config instead of your local version. Like wnnmaw, I'm unfamiliar with emacs, but if it has a configuration similar to vim, you may try finding it on the remote server and configuring it to your likings.

Answer (score 2):

Consider using TRAMP (built in to emacs). It allows you to edit remote files using a local emacs instance (it defaultly uses scp to get files to you, and pushes the edits back again).

Answer (score 0):

python-mode.el should provide this. Get it here:

https://launchpad.net/python-mode

In case you miss something, please file a feature request resp. bug-report at

https://bugs.launchpad.net/python-mode